Geometric explaination of $I=\sqrt{I}$ implies $I$ has no embedded prime ideals
I'm working on the following exercise of Atiyah Commutative Algebra:

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $A$ with $I=\sqrt{I}$ and has a primary decomposition. Show that $I$ has no embedded prime ideals.

I can work this out via definition. However I find myself lacking some intuitions over this. I would like to know whether there is a geometric explaination of $I=\sqrt{I}$, and how it tells us that $I$ has no embedded prime ideals?

I assume that 'geometric explanation' means you are talking about radical ideals in polynomial rings. My geometric interpretation is that primary decompositions of a radical ideal $J \subset \overline{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $\overline{k}$ is an algebraically closed field, coincides with the decomposition of the vanishing set $V(J) \subset \mathbf{A}^n_{\overline{k}}$ into its irreducible components.
There is also a different interpretation. For a commutative ring $R$ and ideal $J\subset R$, we can define $V(J) = \{P \in \text{Spec}(R): J \subset P\}$. In fact, we can define a topology, the so called Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(R)$ where the subsets $V(J)$ are closed. Furthermore, if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $\text{Spec}(R)$ is a Noetherian topological space. With this in mind we can decompose closed sets $V(J)$ into its irreducible components (see 'Algebraic Geometry' by R. Hartshorne first chapter).
Now, we can also prove that we have a one-to-one correspondence between radical ideals $J$ and the sets $V(J)$. This restricts to prime ideals and irreducible closed sets. So, primary decompositions of radical ideals $J$ will indeed coincide with the decomposition of the closed set $V(J)$ into its irreducibles.
